# .NET: assembly sharing between .NET Core and .NET framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

According to what I've read, project needs to target .net standard in order to be consumed simultaneously from other .NET Core and .NET Framework projects, right?

Well, the problem I'm facing is that I need to sign XML and it seems like net standard 2.0 does not support the SignedXml class yet (even though it's supported in .NET Core and .Net Framework)...So, what's the recommended approach to solve this?

Thanks

Luis

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I've opted for going with multi-targeting projects. It's not perfect, but at least I can reuse my library across ASP.NET Core and full ASP.NET projects...